# Best way to manage custom object to extra date and time

Tags: python, pandas

I have an object named datetime but it is not a datetime object.

I have to do some data analysis with this column in Python using the pandas library. The data ends up looking like this:

```
0        2011-01-01 00:00:00
1        2011-01-01 01:00:00
2        2011-01-01 02:00:00
3        2011-01-01 03:00:00
4        2011-01-01 04:00:00
5        2011-01-01 05:00:00
6        2011-01-01 06:00:00
7        2011-01-01 07:00:00
```

And here's what the terminal says datetime is:

```
datetime       object
```

Now I'm wondering the best way to get the hour data into a separate column so I can use that column in my regression analysis. What's the best way to do that because this seems to be a custom object that doesn't have a split command. I would also like to

Is it best to just:

1. Convert to string, do splitting, store month and hours as integers
2. Convert to datetime and somehow extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that df['datetime'] represents your column above, how about:

```
df['hours'] = [ts.hour for ts in pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])]
```

This converts the datetime to a timestamp and then extracts the hour using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use `applymap()`

```
df['Hour'] = df.applymap(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).hour)
```